Is asking how a certain U.S. Code applies to a lawsuit on topic?
For example, if a lawsuit makes a claim that pursuant to U.S.C. #, they are in violation of some offense, is it ok to ask for clarification on how that Code applies specifically? I am not a lawyer or other legal expert, and reading the Code, I could see arguments for it applying or not applying in this specific case, though I do think the arguments on one side are stronger than the other.
Is this something that would be on topic here?

only as long as the lawsuit is not about you!
We do not give legal advice, so lawsuits about you or where you are personally involved are off topic.
If it is a celebrity, it would be best to not just cite someone as "it is reported" but to actually link the docket or charging documents, because those often are vastly different from what the press reports.
